# How to display data from web socket in WPF with MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, api, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to get data through a web socket and display it in a WPF application. I am using Caliburn.Micro for the MMVM. Here is my code:

The view model:

```
 private static WSFuturesResponse futures_response = WSFuturesResponse.GetInstance();

        private double? _last = futures_response.data.last;

        public double? Last
        {
            get
            {
                return _last;
            }
            set
            {
                _last = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Last);
            }
        }
```

Here is the web socket event:

```
public void WebsocketOnMessageReceive(object o, MessageReceivedEventArgs messageReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            // FuturesResponse is a property in this class that I got with 'public WSFuturesResponse FuturesResponse =  WSFuturesResponse.GetInstance();'
            FuturesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSFuturesResponse>(messageReceivedEventArgs.Message);

        }
```

Here is the xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Last, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
```

Lastly the class WSFuturesResponse

```
  public class WSFuturesResponse
    {
        public static WSFuturesResponse ItsInstance;
        public string channel { get; set; }
        public string market { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public WSFuturesData data { get; set; } = new WSFuturesData();

        private static WSFuturesResponse CreateRootClass()
        {
            if (ItsInstance == null)
            {
                ItsInstance = new WSFuturesResponse();
            }

            return ItsInstance;
        }

        public static WSFuturesResponse GetInstance()
        {
            return CreateRootClass();
        }
    }
```

The connection to the web socket works and the data comes back. How can I display it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to set the `Last` property. Is `WebsocketOnMessageReceive` and `Last` defined in the same class?

Comment: No, they aren't in the same class. Last is defined in the Model and WebsocketOnMessageReceive is another class outside of the MMVM pattern. It's in the web socket class. If I need to post more code, please let me know.

Comment: So how is setting a `FuturesResponse` property in the other class supposed to set the data-bound `Last` property...?

Comment: Do you have suggestions how to make it correct @mm8?

Comment: I asked you a question but didn't get an answer. How am I supposed to help you if you don't reveal any details?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing outside your web socket event handler even attempts to access the *FuturesResponse* property your event handler is assigning. If you want to display data that's assigned to the *FuturesResponse* property, something related to your GUI needs to access (read) that *FuturesResponse* property in some way.

Your code outside the web socket event handler is only attempting to work with a *WSFuturesResponse* instance created and returned by *WSFuturesResponse GetInstance()*. But that is obviously **not** the *WSFuturesResponse* instance created by *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSFuturesResponse>* and assigned to the *FuturesResponse* property the rest of your code outside the web socket event handler is never accessing.

I don't know what you are trying to realize with this *WSFuturesResponse GetInstance()* method of yours. It looks very much to me like you are implementing a singleton pattern for response data -- which does not make sense *at all*, because there is not just one and only single response ever received. Thus, and as an aside, i would like you to also try getting an understanding for yourself (so you can learn from your mistakes) of what made you believe that the singleton pattern would be applicable for something that is not really a single instance situation (not a single response, but multiple responses).

Comment: You are right, I wasn't trying to access the FuturesResponse property that the event handler is assigning. I implemented now a singleton pattern for the WebSocket class. In that way the event handler is assigning the data to FuturesResponse and from the GUI I can access that property and read from it. At least this my logic but it still doesn't show up in the GUI. Any suggestions?